# Prevent .NET from writing to C:\Windows\Temp

Tags: .net, web-services, permissions

I've got a C# application that I'm trying to push out to a distributed network.  The application works fine locally (as always), but when I push it out to the network, it doesn't work because it can't write to the C:\Windows\Temp directory.  I'm not actually calling any code that writes to that directory, but I imagine it is caused by my calls to a webservice, given the following exception:

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\cyalinh1.0.cs' could not be 
>   found error CS2008: No inputs specified '.  Please see InnerException 
>   for more details.

Is there any way to prevent .NET from writing to the Temp directory?  Is it a setting in the .config file?

**UPDATE**

Can SGEN be used to prevent the creation of those dynamically created classes from the webservice?

Comment: I don't have an answer other than to tell you that what you're running into is the fact that when the run time executes your assembly, it actually needs to do another round of Just In Time compilation to get the code from IL to machine code.

Comment: Can I prevent these dynamic class compilations with SGENing the dll that is called over a web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that webservices require read/write permission to %SystemRoot%\Temp ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwzs111e.aspx)).

From [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34046315/problem-writing-to-cwin.aspx):

> If you're running ASP.NET 2.0 or
>   above, you can assign the required
>   permissions with the command:
>
> ```
> aspnet_regiis -GA MachineName\Account
> ```

This [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingWhereXmlSerializerOutputsTemporaryAssemblies.aspx) contains instructions on how to change the location of the SystemRoot\Temp folder used for this (as well as instructions on how to use reflector to determine the setting in web.config to set for a situation like this)

Comment: Is there also a setting, or perhaps an environment variable (a la `TMPDIR`), to set the temp directory path?

Comment: Edited post to add link for instructions on how to change the temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that you are using some function which auto-generates temporary code.  It needs a location to do this.  So yes, while you can prevent it from writing code to that specific location, the only way to prevent it from generating code (that must be stored somewhere) is to not use a function that generates temporary classes.

Answer (score 0):

the process that runs this code (IIS related NT account?) should have an appropriate  permission set read more http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+writing+files+permissions

Answer (score 0):

Josh,

My guess would be that the call you are making is trying to kick off a debugging session on the target PC.  It is trying to pull up the source file, after having an exception.

The root cause is likely an exception in the web service call.

To mitigate the write to the temp folder, you might be able to disable just-in-time debugging on the target machines:
something like `<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="false"/>`  in app config

I did some digging.  It looks like the issue may be on the server, not the client machines.  If you add read/write permissions to the temp folder for the user hosting the webservice, it may be OK.  Sorry for the crazy advice above...

Answer (score 0):

Searched so many forums and finally fixed it..This worked for me..here you go!!

1. right click c:\windows\temp folder
2. under security tab, add the iisuser account to the list of users and give read/write/execute access (or) full rights
3. restart the website

Thats it !!!...check you application which consumes the deployed web service

This should do..