# Establish connection to Dynamics CRM Online web service from Windows 8 metro style app

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, windows-8, dynamics-crm-online

I have serious problem with creating a connection to dynamics CRM online from my Window 8 metro style application.

My code works fine under normal (full) .net framework, but fails under WinRT

```
private IOrganizationService OrgService { get; set; }
private ClientCredentials ClientCreds { get; set; }
private ClientCredentials DeviceCreds { get; set; }
//(..)
ClientCreds = new ClientCredentials();
ClientCreds.UserName.UserName = "some_account@hotmail.com";
ClientCreds.UserName.Password = "sample_password";

DeviceCreds = DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice();

Uri orgServiceUri = new Uri("https://sampleaddress.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

OrgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceUri, null, ClientCreds, DeviceCreds);
```

The last line of this code gives an exception:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)

Probably this class tries to save some file somewhere, which is not permitted in metro style apps.

Anybody can help with that ? How to bypass this behavior or OrganizationServiceProxy class ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is using services, you may be running into a problem I had: having to control the output of generated classes that come back over the wire.  The code has to be JITed somewhere and that is often the temp directory.

See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717574/prevent-net-from-writing-to-c-windows-temp) for controlling the output directory.