# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)

Tags: c#, wcf, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I have a c# executable that triggers the WCF webservice in the same server.It was working fine until it started to throws this error message

```
Message : Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\mchgnxs3.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

What I tried so far:
Provided read/write access to the account that triggers the WCF

Recently the server crashed and restored from a backup server.Is there any chance that it is related to the error?

Comment: Check the C Drive and make sure that file `'C:\Windows\TEMP\mchgnxs3.0.cs` is there, and that its permissions allow access by the account the c# executable is running under (logged on as).  It's possible that the restore from backup did not include either the file or the appropriate permissions for the file.

Comment: This is not about the file or its name.Everytime the temp file name changes when I run the application

Comment: It seems the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717574/prevent-net-from-writing-to-c-windows-temp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it.You have to provide the write access to temporary folder .
I was providing this access to different user.The correct user id is the one that is mentioned in application pool of your web service.

Comment: This happened to us after upgrading to Windows 10 and using a WinForms app; Before with Windows 7, was working fine.

Enabling full control to the user did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your project storing in Windows's temporal folder and 'mchgnxs3.0.cs' file can be deleted. Otherwise you should try to rename your script file (maybe 'mchgnxs3.0.cs' to 'mchgnxs3_0.cs').